# Issues with "On Open" Applescript handler in Yosemite

Tags: applescript, osx-yosemite

In using Applescript in OSX 10.10 (Yosemite), it seems Apple has changed some of the default behavior.

```
on open dropped_files
   display dialog (count of dropped_files)
end open
```

This very basic Applescript highlights the problem. If I select a group of 6 files from the Finder, and drop/drop onto a compiled version of this script, I get the response "2" and then the response "4". It should be responding "6"... but it's almost as if Finder is parsing the files into smaller groups. If I do this again, I get a different combination of numbers, so it does not seem to be consistent.

This is not the desired behavior for my application, any ideas for a solution? I never saw this behavior with older versions of Applescript.

Comment: I've submitted this as a bug to apple (report# 20021353) after discussing this in #macdev. Still open to other workarounds in the meantime!

Comment: Are some of the files quarantined?  You can check using Terminal: “xattr -p com.apple.quarantine /path/to/file”.

Comment: Very interesting suggestion Chris! From my review, that's exactly what is going on. It's submitting the quarantined files as one group and the non-quarantined files as another group. Rather surprising behavior.

After removing the quarantine attribute with this command:
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine *

It reported the proper number of files.

Comment: I've updated the bug report as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bizarre effect is due to quarantined files. Quarantined files can be checked with the command:

```
xattr -p com.apple.quarantine *
```

Depending on the sort order of the quarantined/non-quarantined files, it will separately execute the "on open" handler for each group (be it quarantined or non-quarantined): e.g., 1 - quarantined, 4 - non-quarantined, 3 - quarantined. You'll notice there are two groups of quarantined files being submitted in this example, and that's because of how that particular list was sorted and submitted to the on open handler.

This behavior is rather surprising, and I've submitted it as a bug report to Apple. The quarantine attribute can be removed with this command:

```
sudo xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine *
```

to show the correct number of files. Also, see the Applescript trick above by regulus6633 for a clever workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's strange. This workaround seems to work. We can take advantage of properties and the "on quit" handler which is automatically run after the "on open" handler. So just run your normal code in the "on quit" handler using dFiles. Remember to set dFiles to {} at the very end else dFiles will not work properly the next time you drop files.

```
property dFiles : {}

on open dropped_files
    set dFiles to dFiles & dropped_files
end open

on quit
    display dialog (count of dFiles)
    set dFiles to {}
    continue quit
end quit
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It worked, but then on re-running the script it multiplied the numbers...e.g.

7, then 14, then 21 when I dragged the same list of files onto it.  I'm not sure why it's not resetting itself back to zero.

It turns out it was related to the quarantine, I just don't understand why it would split up the groups of quarantined files. It will also address these files in order, e.g.

1 - quarantined
2 - not quarantined
3 - not quarantined
4 - quarantined
5 - not quarantined

It will report this as 1, 2, 1, 1 in the count as it alternates between quarantined and non.

Comment: You need the line "set dFiles to {}" at the end of the script to make it reset back to zero.

Comment: I included that in there. Maybe it doesn't work on compiled scripts?