# AppleScript "on open" misbehavior

Tags: applescript

I have a list of jpeg images on a local server that I use an AppleScript droplet to resize in Photoshop. I use "on open" to do this, but something strange happens: they open in two parts.

The files are named as follows:

```
0_203.jpg
1_203.jpg
2_203.jpg
3_203.jpg
4_203.jpg
5_203.jpg
6_203.jpg
7_203.jpg
8_203.jpg
9_203.jpg
10_203.jpg
11_203.jpg
12_203.jpg
13_203.jpg
14_203.jpg
15_203.jpg
16_203.jpg
17_203.jpg
18_203.jpg
19_203.jpg
20_203.jpg
```

The script should do its actions to each file in turn, but something strange happens: it breaks the files into two groups and runs the script twice. The script splits the groups like this:

```
1_203.jpg
2_203.jpg
3_203.jpg
4_203.jpg
5_203.jpg
6_203.jpg
7_203.jpg
8_203.jpg
9_203.jpg
10_203.jpg
11_203.jpg
12_203.jpg
```

...and then runs again with these files...

```
0_203.jpg
13_203.jpg
14_203.jpg
15_203.jpg
16_203.jpg
17_203.jpg
18_203.jpg
19_203.jpg
20_203.jpg
```

What the hell is going on here?

Here's the test script I used to debug:

```
on open myItems
    set myList to {}

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ":"
    repeat with thisItem in myItems
        set newItem to thisItem as string
        copy newItem to end of myList
    end repeat
    display dialog myList as string

end open
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the script is -- anything that starts with "on open." I added a script I used up top.

Comment: Have you tried replacing this: `set newItem to thisItem as string
        copy newItem to end of myList` with: `set end of myList to (thisItem as text)` ?  Additionally, whenever messing with **text item delimiters**, it is good practice to save the original delimiters first, then set them to the original value when your script finishes.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's standard practice to reset the delimiters -- I just didn't bother since it's a test script. As for your suggestion, it doesn't make a difference. The script splits those files into two groups, then runs individually on each set. The reason I know this is because it displays a dialog twice, yet the code only has one dialog display after the repeat. It really seems like this isn't an AppleScript issue and may in fact be a server-side issue.

Comment: The answer is the files are set to quarantined by the system. The answer below was the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the question and answers posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827249/issues-with-on-open-applescript-handler-in-yosemite/28839149#28839149). I gave a work-around as a solution.

Comment: This was the answer. Thanks!